# perl unintialized value: how to make more meaningful warnings?

Tags: perl

in Perl, I can see warnings like

```
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at stat_plots.pl line 446.
```

However, I would like to make changes to perl, or add a subroutine at the beginning of the script, so that this warning would show an error like

```
Hash key {index} is not defined at stat_plots.pl line 446.
```

This would save a lot of time in the debugging process, and make the code look a lot nicer without having to add dozens of

```
if (!defined $hash{$key}) {
   print "\$hash{$key} isn't defined.\n";
}
```

and make each script much longer and messier.

Is there a way to get perl to do this?

Comment: What version of Perl are you using?  I think as far back as 5.10 or 5.12 they made the warning nicer: `Use of uninitialized value $foo in concatenation at...`

Comment: I can see how this could be done with `$SIG{__WARN__}`, `caller`, `PPI`, and `PadWalker`, Probably more trouble than it's worth, especially if upgrading perl (see Jim Davis' comment above) will address this problem.

Comment: @mob let's not go there... :)

Comment: it's perl version 5.22.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't change Perl to do that. But the people who maintain Perl have already changed Perl to do that for you.

```
$ perl -Mwarnings -E'say $_."XX"'
Use of uninitialized value $_ in concatenation (.) or string at -e line 1.
XX
```

This change was released in Perl 5.10.0 (in December 2007).

> **New or Changed Diagnostics**
>
> *Use of uninitialized value*
>
> Perl will now try to tell you the name of the variable (if any) that was undefined.

(From [perl5100delta](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perl5100delta.pod))

So the answer to your question is - upgrade your version of Perl.

Comment: Why not `perl -W`?

Comment: Good question. Habit probably. My fingers autocorrect `use` statements to `-M` options in command-line scripts. But, yes, `-w` or `-W` would work just as well.

Answer (score 6):

**No**, you can't just change Perl to do that.

What you can do is turn on `use diagnostics`, but it will only explain the error message to you. In your case, that's this:

> Use of uninitialized value in say at scratch.pl line
>   1324 (#1)
>
> (W uninitialized) An undefined value was used as if it were already
>       defined.  It was interpreted as a "" or a 0, but maybe it was a mistake.
>      To suppress this warning assign a defined value to your variables.
>
> To help you figure out what was undefined, perl will try to tell you
>       the name of the variable (if any) that was undefined.  In some cases
>       it cannot do this, so it also tells you what operation you used the
>       undefined value in.  Note, however, that perl optimizes your program
>       and the operation displayed in the warning may not necessarily appear
>       literally in your program.  For example, "that $foo" is usually
>       optimized into "that " . $foo, and the warning will refer to the
>       concatenation (.) operator, even though there is no . in
>       your program.

But that doesn't tell you anything you didn't already know, and it comes at considerable cost.